# Howto block wifi-messages flooding syslog?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kernel, syslog, rsyslog

I'm Martin.

I am using Ubuntu "Xenial".

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

For Wifi I'm using a tp-link TL-WN823N adapter.
This adapter creates lots of annoying kernel messages flooding the sylsog of my pc like this:

```
Aug 15 09:39:36 trusty1 kernel: [17180.716089] RTW: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=2 SmartPS=2 
Aug 15 09:39:50 trusty1 kernel: [17194.744114] RTW: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlxd0374517c218) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
Aug 15 09:39:50 trusty1 kernel: [17194.744123] RTW: rtl8192e_set_FwPwrMode_cmd: Mode=0 SmartPS=2 
Aug 15 09:39:52 trusty1 kernel: [17196.748081] RTW: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlxd0374517c218) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
```

What I tried is to create a file /etc/rsyslog.d/53-rtw.conf

```
:msg, contains, "*RTW*" ~
```

but this doesn't have an effect any longer.

I think I have to filter kernel messages being logged by rsyslog, but I don't know how.

Any suggestions?
Help appreciated.

Martin

Comment: I'm using the following syntax: `if $msg contains "your.expression.here" then stop`

Comment: A better idea would be to fix the flipping of the `Mode=` value.

Comment: @Artur I'm using now the following syntax and it works fine:
:msg, contains, "RTW" stop
Thanks
Martin

Comment: @waltinator how can I fix the flipping of Mode of the interface?
Martin

Comment: You should start by asking a new question. Questions asked in comments are impossible for future AskUbuntu users to find.